# Best way to implement a multi-user goal list?

Tags: authentication

I want to make a list of goals for my family and I that we are all going to follow.

I generally know how I'll implement the list part. Just a todo-list-esque app where you only cross or uncross things off on it. I haven't decided with what I'll implement that part, mostly because I'm not sure how the multi-user part will go. 
I figured each person can log in with Facebook or Twitter, and based on your login you'd be able to see what you've checked off.
I've never built a login before, or built based off of a logged in user.

Which web frameworks would be best for this? How would you implement this?

Comment: What programming languages do you know?

Comment: @rdegges my top ones are probably JavaScript, Python, and Java.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you know Javascript well, it sounds like you're best bet is to just use Node.js and a simple web framework like Express.js.

This will allow you to write you server-side code in Javascript, which should make the process simpler for you.

For handling authentication / etc., if you're looking for a stupid-simple authentication library you can use [express-stormpath](https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/) -- it supports social login as well as username/password stuff.

If you're looking for a smaller solution, you can use something like [passport.js](http://passportjs.org/) and use the [third-party plugins](http://passportjs.org/guide/providers/) for social login.